# Close modal dialog from the directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem and I can't understand the reason, because it works on local server, but on production doesn't.

I have a directive like this:

```
calcP.directive('modalDialog', function() {
    return {

        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            show: '=',
            types: '=',
        },
        replace: true, 
        transclude: true, 

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('scope', scope);
            scope.dialogStyle = {};
            if (attrs.width)
                scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
            if (attrs.height)
                scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
            scope.hideModal = function() {
                scope.show = false;
              delete  scope.types.individual;

            };

        },
        template: "<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'><div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='hideModal()'></div><div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'><div class='ng-modal-close' ng-click='hideModal()'>X</div><div class='ng-modal-dialog-content' ng-transclude></div></div></div>"
    };
});
```

In my controller I have as fallows:

```
$scope.modalShown = false;
    $scope.toggleModal = function() {
        $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
        console.log('modalShown', $scope.modalShown);
    };
```

In the view I have as fallows:

```
<modal-dialog show='modalShown' types="types">
```

So, as far as I see using console.log the toggleModal() doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try function hoisting?

Instead of direct function assign to $scope

```
 //what you did
 $scope.toggleModal = function() {
      $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
      console.log('modalShown', $scope.modalShown);
 };
```

try to define function separately and assign it to the $scope like

```
 $scope.toggleModal = toggleModal;
 function toggleModal () {
      $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
      console.log('modalShown', $scope.modalShown);
 };
```